# Are there any phonetic pangrams for Mandarin and other Chinese languages?

Tags: pronunciation

A phonetic pangram is a bit of text which uses all the **sounds**, or phonemes, in a language (as opposed to the letters of characters). Very useful for practising pronunciation. This is one in English:

> “The beige hue on the waters of the loch impressed all, including the
>   French queen, before she heard that symphony again, just as young
>   Arthur wanted.”

Does such a thing exist for Mandarin or other Chinese languages? In English, there are around 44 phonemes ( https://www.dyslexia-reading-well.com/44-phonemes-in-english.html ), but Chinese languages would presumably have much more.

Answer (score 2):

> but chinese languages would presumably have much more

well, the cantonese has 1800+ syllables. the short answer to your question is: **no**.

the long answer:

cantonese has 19 initial, 56 final and 9 tone. though 19 * 56 * 9 = 9576, fortunately, there’re limited combinations of initial, final and tone. nowadays, only 1800+ syllables exist, for 8000 - 50,000 chinese characters.

an example: the initial “**s**” combined with the final “**e**”, it become “**se**”, this “sound” has 6 tones. that, each syllable represent several characters:

[se1](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/se1.Mp3) | 些奓奢畬賒

[se2](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/se2.Mp3) | 寫捨瀉灺舍

[se3](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/se3.Mp3) | 赦卌卸厙庫涻瀉灺猞舍騇

[se4](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/se4.Mp3) | 蛇佘畬輋闍

[se5](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/se5.Mp3) | 社舍

[se6](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/se6.Mp3) | 射社麝

[cantonese syllable, sound: **e**](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/pho-rel.php?final=e)

tone is very important in cantonese, without the proper tone, one cannot get the correct character from hearing.

a text with 1800+ characters is extremely long, for the purpose of practising pronunciation, that i don’t think such thing would exist.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be correct. Other sources give 67 phonemes for Mandarin for instance - https://www.quora.com/How-many-phonemes-are-there-in-Mandarin-Chinese .. if you look at the English example it doesn’t have every single sound (every consonant-vowel combination), just the building blocks to make every sound.